# how to adjust width of geom_bar to same width

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 TEMP %>%   ggplot(aes(x= Count,y=reorder(Species,Count))) + geom_col(position = "dodge") + ggtitle("Insects abundance during 2017~2019") + ylab("Insects") + xlab("Mean Number")   + facet_wrap(~ CLASS,ncol = 1,scales = 'free') + theme_bw()
```

[image]

I want to make the top panel and the bottom panel having same width bar. But even though I set the width in the `geom_col(width = .5)`. They are still different width. What's the problem. Thanks for everyone who care about my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post a reprex with data, I'll just use the mtcars data set.

The `space` argument in `facet_grid()` allows the width of each facet to be determined by the number of x or y values.

Without `space = "free_y"`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = factor(carb))) + 
        geom_bar(width = 0.5) + 
        facet_grid(am~., scales = "free")
```

[image]

With `space = "free_y"`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(y = factor(carb))) + 
        geom_bar(width = 0.5) + 
        facet_grid(am~., scales = "free", space = "free_y")
```

[image]